# Angular Material Theme on directive issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I created a custom directive :

```
<my-directive> </my-directive>
```

In my .js file

```
angular.module('myApp').controller(){
 // Inside here i have a function which enable the button to display a dialog when on click . The function displays a templateUrl which shows up my form .
   function openDialog(){
      // i have a templateUrl here
      templateUrl : 'The page containing my form structure'

    }
}
angular.module('myApp').directive('myDirective'){
return {
    // I take it the theme as :  
          scope : { 
                 theme: '@'
             }
   // inside here i link it to a templateUrl which shows a button.
            templateUrl: 'The page containing my button'
}
}
angular.module('myApp').config(function($mdThemingProvider){
       $mdThemingProvider.theme('forest')
           .primaryPalette('brown')
           .accentPalette('green');
    /// i created a custom theme here 
}
```

In my Html file calling the directive:

```
<my-directive theme="forest"><my-directive>
```

But it doesnt work.

Question: Because of my multiple templateUrl, is it causing my theme to not work on the form ?? Or am i doing it wrong?

Some References i am looking at: 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BppORB

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MJJqEp

Comment: angular.module.('myApp') is wrong; same for angular.module.('myApp').controller()... is it just typos?

Comment: sorry it's just typo. @Dario

Comment: allright...your code it's hard to test because of several errors but one thing I notice is that you are not declaring forest variable in the controller...maybe ```'forest'``` is already working? ```<my-directive theme="'forest'"><my-directive>``` ?

Comment: what do you mean by declaring forest variable in the controller?? as i take it the theme variable in the directive. then i am stuck already

Comment: you pass it to the directive, but where do you set it? I don't see it in your code. Will you prepare some fiddle so it will be easier to help you?

Comment: I added 2 new codepen which i want did it based on.

Comment: The examples you provided work via the `md-colors` directive with manual styling.

Comment: yes. but they only change the background color, what if i intend to change like my form elements ? For e.g Button color etc. How do i approach this? @kuhnroyal

Comment: Most elements provided by angular-material can be styled with `md-theme`.  https://material.angularjs.org/latest/Theming/04_multiple_themes

Comment: @kuhnroyal i have read and realise it cant really work together with the codepen I've provided